# How to elegantly fill an array/list with values

Tags: c#, arrays

How do I construct an array of doubles 'in a *smart way*'? I need it filled with 10-ish values like this,

```
var d = new double[] { -0.05, 0.0, 0.05};
```

but would prefer a more dynamic building like this

```
    var d = new List<double>();
    for (var dd = -0.05; dd < 0.05; dd += 0.05)
    {
        d.Add(dd);
    }
```

It looks chunky though and commands too much attention in my code compared to the rather mundane service performed.

Can I write it smarter?

BR,
Anders

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you have, its easily read and maintainable.

Comment: Write code that you can look at and know right away what it does. Readability is one of the most important parts of writing software. Give someone your first and second example and ask them which one is easier for them to understand.

Comment: Why would you *prefer* a dynamic binding? If the values are known at compile time then your first suggestion is by far the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Enumerable.Range`:

```
  int n = 7;
  double step = 0.05; 

  double[] d = Enumerable
    .Range(-n / 2, n)
    .Select(i => i * step)
    .ToArray();

  Console.Write(string.Join("; ", d));
```

Outcome

```
-0.15; -0.1; -0.05; 0; 0.05; 0.1; 0.15
```

If `n = 3` then we'll get

```
-0.05; 0; 0.05
```

Answer (score 2):

All this depends on what you would call "Smart Way". Performance ? Readability ? Maintenance ?

On one hand, if you have only three elements and the values are static, your first line of code is perfectly fine and it is the "Smartest Way". A small improvement would be (if you want a list) :

```
List<double> d = new List<double> { -0.05, 0, 0.05 };
```

On another hand, if you have lots of values, a for loop may be easier to write.

Linq is also possible so writing something like this :

```
List<double> d = Enumerable.Range(-1,3).Select(x => x * 0.05).ToList();
```

is really good looking because you are using Linq and it rocks, but is it really more readable ? More performant ? Smarter ?

All in all, it all depends on what you want and what you need to do. There is no straight answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use linq, not quite sure if it is smart:

```
double start = -0.05;
double step = 0.05;
var result = Enumerable.Repeat(0, 3).Select((x, i) =>start+step*i).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach if you are initalzing a lot of array, you might want to use `IEnumerable` and `yield` in a helper class

```
public static IEnumerable<double> RangeEx(double start, double finish, double step)
{
    for (var dd = start; dd < finish; dd += step) 
        yield return dd;
}
```

**Usage**

```
var array = RangeEx(-0.05, 0.05, 0.05).ToArray();
```